# How to replace sub elements in xml files using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, system.xml

I have 2 xml files:

File 1

```
<xml version.....> 
  <System>
    <General>
      <Instrument>
        <Specific>
          <Name>...</Name>
        </Specific>
      <Instrument>
    </General>
  <System>
```

File 2

```
<System>
  <Specific>
    <Name>...</Name>
    <age>...</age>
    ....
  </Specific>
<System>
```

File 1 only has one entry under the element Specific, File 2 has multiple entries under the element specific. I need to replace all the entries under Specific in File 1 with the entries under Specific in File 2.

How is this be done in c#, using System.Xml.Linq or System.Xml???

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This site helps solving issues with your code. You should **post your code** here when you have results which are different from expected, or when you get an error. You also should describe **what results you have and what is expected** and/or provide error details. After that community will help you to solve issues and (sometimes) it'll give you some guidance. That is how stackoverflow works. As you can see, your question doesn't have all appropriate information. Please **edit** your question and add code with other required information if you want to get some help.

Comment: You could take a look at `LINQ to XML` . But you should give it a try first, before asking the SO community to solve it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

You can do that iteratively adding nodes from one element to another like this using LinqToXml.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace XmlReplacer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var doc1 = XDocument.Load(@"d:\temp\file1.xml");                     
            var doc2 = XDocument.Load(@"d:\temp\file2.xml");
            var specElement1 = doc1.Root.Element("General").Element("Instrument").Element("Specific");
            var specElement2 = doc2.Root.Element("Specific");

            specElement1.RemoveAll();

            foreach (var xElement in specElement2.Elements())
            {
                specElement1.Add(xElement);
            }
            doc1.Save(@"d:\temp\file3.xml");
        }
    }
}
```

Result is file3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<System>
    <General>
        <Instrument>
            <Specific>
                <Name>Test2</Name>
                <Age>10</Age>
            </Specific>
        </Instrument>
    </General>
</System>
```